# Splitting a nested list with a string value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, list-comprehension

How would I be able to make a list comprehension that concatenates the input lists with and `'X'` string as the separator. Note that the expected output will be string. The code below does not work please modify it.

```
val = [['_', '_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']]
output = ' '.join([cols if c != len(row)-1 else cols + 'X' for row in enumerate(formatted_list) for c,cols in enumerate(row)])
print(output)
```

input:

```
val = [['_', '_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']]
```

output:

```
_ _ _ _ X _ _ _ _ _
```

input:

```
val = [['t', 'python'], ['2', '6', '7'], ['9', '5']]
```

output:

```
t python X 2 6 7 X 9 5
```

Comment: Are the given output examples the actual incorrect output, or the desired output?

Comment: desired outputs

Comment: The outputs are not consistent.  In the first example, there is no `X` between the elements of the first sub-list `_ _ _ _`, but the second example has `t X python`.  What is the criteria for deciding whether to put X between the elements of a sub-list?

Comment: That was a mistake on my end, fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: If your input is just a list of lists of strings, you could just try this:

   `output = ' X '.join([' '.join(v) for v in val])`

But I see that some of your inputs could be integers as well, which means you'd need to perform a conversion to string first.

    `val = [[str(i) for i in x] for x in val]`

Comment: I meant to have the  nested  lists as strings only. So I updated the test case once again. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Why list comprehension? It would be better without.

Comment: Use a list comprehension to apply the joining operation (with `' '`) to each inner list, then use a single join (with `'X'`) to join those results. Problems like this require *breaking the problem down into logical steps* first, and thinking about what needs to happen in what order. That part is your responsibility before asking, and is not a question about programming. Once you have a general process in mind, you should be able to either solve the problem, or come up with a *specific* question about *one* of the steps.

Comment: If you are struggling through reasoning out the logic for a problem, you probably want the help of a **discussion forum** instead, which Stack Overflow **is not**. We want questions that can potentially help other people who find them with a search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test_lst = [['_', '_', '_', '_'], ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']]
sep_inner, sep_outer = ' ', ' X '

res = sep_outer.join([sep_inner.join(lst) for lst in test_lst])
print(res)
```